# UIViewController Image Touch Events

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have an image in a UIViewController which can be zoomed in and out. What I want is to include some areas of the image where the user can tap and more information shows up on that screen.

I was wondering how I should approach this?

Note, the image must be able to zoom in and out; and the areas where they touch would increase/decrease according to the image zoom. (If that is possible).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Feel free to pick a username and stay awhile. :-) Generally, we don't use greetings in posts, so I'm removing them. (Not that anybody isn't welcome, but it isn't done.) Remember to select the correct answer to your questions. It encourages folks to help you. Once again, welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [UIPinchGesture Recognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPinchGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UITabGesture Recognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: And how would I have it so that information (more images) show up when an area gets tapped?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UIScrollView for this. If you want certain areas to have info overlays like the map, you can store a list of "hot spots" and test touch events against the list and see if that area has been tapped.